# PyCharm Matplotlib "UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure. plt.show()"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am having problems with `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` function. I am using **PyCharm** on **Linux**, and i have a **VirtualEnv**. When i execute the file *x.py* in the built terminal in PyCharm (using venv) like this

> $ python x.py

everything works fine, the function `plt.show()` renders and shows the plotted graph well. i did add `print(matplotlib.get_backend())` to see which backend was used by default and the result was **GTK3Agg**.

The problem starts when i use the option Run and not the terminal. Then i get an error message

> UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI
>   backend, so cannot show the figure. plt.show()

Anyways, i searched online and according to [this](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) and other links, i had to add `backend: GTK3Agg` in *.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc* . The file did not exist so i created it myself. Now when i run again, i get the following error messages:

> ```
> raise ImportError('backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo') from e ImportError: backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo
> ```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Looks like you have two environments, one where GTK and dependencies are installed, and one, which is used by PyCharm, where those are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointing out that i had two environments, one where GTK and dependencies are installed, and one, which is used by PyCharm, where those are missing.

I had to go to `Settings > Project interpreter` and install **matplotlib**, **pycairo** and **PyGObject**.

Also neccessary to install pycairo and PyGObject were these packages, which i had to install from the terminal:

```
sudo dnf install cairo-devel (or libcairo2 in ubuntu)
sudo dnf install python3-devel
sudo dnf install gobject-introspection-devel
sudo dnf install cairo-gobject-devel
```

Now i can use GTK3Agg as my backend.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Linux Mint 20.3) the issue came from installing PyCharm from the Software Manager. PyCharm then was installed with flatpak

```
flatpak list
```

should give show you an idea if it is so too.

There are issues with that version. Have a look at:
https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/issues/15

I could fix it by installing PyCharm with snapd.
https://thesecmaster.com/3-ways-to-install-pycharm-on-linux-mint-and-ubuntu/

then: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk`
and within PyCharm I had to add

"future" and "matplotlib"

More information about it:
When you run PyCharm the first time (installed from Software Manager) you receive:

> https://www.flathub.org

---

### | Warning: You are running an unofficial Flatpak version of PyCharm !!! |

Please open issues under: https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/issues

This version is running inside a container and is therefore not able
to access SDKs on your host system!